# Why my realm recycle view not showing any data ?

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have implemented RecyclerView show some realm table data. I've created adapter by extending from RealmRecyclerViewAdapter. Even thought I have 3 rows in table (Which I checked by result debugging) nothing showing up in the list. I'm using `'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'` adapter and Realm 3.7.2

Here's my code.

*Adapter class.*

```
 public class UserListAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<User,UserListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public UserListAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<User> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        super(data, autoUpdate);
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = getItem(position);
        holder.home.setText(user.getUid());
        holder.name.setText(user.getName());
        holder.home.setText(user.getHouse().getName());
        if(user.isStatus()) {
            holder.status.setText("Active");
        }else{
            holder.status.setText("Inactive");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int index) {
        return getItem(index).getUid();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.column_id)
        TextView id;

        @BindView(R.id.column_name)
        TextView name;

        @BindView(R.id.column_house)
        TextView home;

        @BindView(R.id.status_button)
        Button status;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            status.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v.getId() ==  R.id.status){
                //TODO: create interface and add method tho trigger when status click
            }else{
                //TODO: create interface and add method tho trigger when item click
            }

        }
    }
}
```

code fragment for setting adapter

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
            RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
            listAdapter = new UserListAdapter(users,true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewDividerVertical(2));
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}
```

I could have conver `RealmResults<User>` in to `ArrayList<User>` and implement normal RecyclerView Adapter and get it done. But As I've understand `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` will result auto update result data in case of data change. But i'm not 100% clear on that too. Can any one explain how that works ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()){
        RealmResults<User> users = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
        listAdapter = new UserListAdapter(users,true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewDividerVertical(2));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
} // <--- auto-close!
```

If you close the Realm instance then the results bound to it become invalidated, and `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` checks against `isValid()` which will return `false` because you've closed the Realm, so it will be shown with `0` element count.

Refer to proper lifecycle management for UI thread Realm instance (`onCreate()` open, `onDestroy()` close) [in the documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your data is invalid and **getItemCount()** method which is implemented in [**RealmRecyclerViewAdapter**](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java) returns 0.

Comment: you are right. Adding a link will help future readers  https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java

Comment: Please, I still don't get it. Where should I change ? And how come my  OrderedRealmCollection<User> Nullable in my Adapter constructor and the one in the example not.